# XeLaTeX does not compile with many tcolorboxes

Tags: errors, compiling, tcolorbox

I am attempting to compile a document using XeLaTeX. Both in TeXstudio and TeXworks, it fails to produce any PDF. I narrowed down the problem to be the number of `tcolorbox`s included. If I remove one of them, any one, it compiles again.

I cannot reproduce a good MWE because of the sheer number of used `tcolorbox`s (more than one hundred).

The log says

```
Sorry, but xelatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully 
contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: 
C:\Users\Fabiano\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\xelatex.log
dvipdfmx:fatal: File ended prematurely
No output PDF file written.
```

Then, in the `xelatex.log`, the first FATAL errors are

```
2021-09-29 15:19:51,966-0300 FATAL xelatex.core - Too many open files: path="C:\Users\Fabiano\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/tfm/public/cm\cmr10.tfm"
2021-09-29 15:19:51,966-0300 FATAL xelatex.core - Function: fdopen
2021-09-29 15:19:51,967-0300 FATAL xelatex.core - Result: 24
```

So, any advice to how to proceed?

EDIT

The code used for the tcolorboxes is

```
\NewTColorBox{eblock}{O{} m m m}{
  enhanced,
  breakable           = unlimited,
  skin                = bicolor,
  boxrule             = 0pt,
  fontupper           = \sffamily,
  fontlower           = \sffamily,
  fonttitle           = \sffamily,
  colframe            = #2,
  coltitle            = white,
  interior style      = {left color=secondtablecolor,right color=white},
  colbacklower        = white,
  left                = 2pt,
  right               = 2pt,
  top                 = 2pt,
  bottom              = 2pt,
  middle              = 1pt,
  before upper*       = {\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{hangparas}{1em}{1}},
  after upper*        = {\end{hangparas}\end{minipage}},
  segmentation at break = false,
  title               = {
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=0pt,colsep=0pt}
    \begin{tblr}{Xr}
      {\bfseries#3} & {\bfseries#4}\\
    \end{tblr}
  },
  sharpish corners,
  #1
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code using `tcolorbox`es? Normally, I wouldn't expect the package `tcolorbox` to open external files, or if it does, to leave them open. Does your document contain other stuff that opens many files, like loading many fonts, style files (with sub libraries) etc?

Comment: I edited to show the code for the tcolorboxes. "breakable = unlimited" is not really needed (none of them are very long, I just attempted that to see if I could improve the number of boxes in the document).

There are just three fonts: the main, one for the tcolorboxes and one for sectioning.

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example that you have issue with, otherwise others cannot test properly

Comment: Which package defines `\NewTColorBox`? Apparently not `tcolorbox`. Please give a complete example that generates the problem when adding 300 copies of boxes.

Comment: As I said, my trouble with a MWE is that the issue just happens when a compile more than about one hundred of the tcolorboxes. Less than that, it compiles like a charm. I thought in to break the document in smaller ones, but then I would lost the cross references.

Comment: Yes, understood, but give the code for a document that produces at least one of these bad boxes. Adding a few hundred copies then is not the problem

Comment: I will attempt cut the fat in the preamble and narrow down the minimum packages that reproduce the trouble. Then I will edit the post again. For now, thanks for the attention.

About \NewTColorBox, it is the expl3 version of \newtcolorbox as far I know. The trouble persists in use just \newtcolorbox. In truth, I just changed to the \NewTColorBox to see if the problem was still there with an expl3 syntax.

Comment: Ok, I discovered the behavior is being caused by the tblr (from tabularray package) within the tcolorbox title. I am creating an working around now.

Comment: If you succeed, please answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the issue. It is the tblr environment inside the tcolobox' title that is causing the too many open files. The very existence of that environment there was bad LaTeXing of my part. Do not take me wrong, tabularray is an amazing package and I find it very useful, but there was a cannon to hit a fly.

```
title               = {
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=0pt,colsep=0pt}
    \begin{tblr}{Xr}
      {\bfseries#3} & {\bfseries#4}\\
    \end{tblr}
  },
```

is easily substituted by

```
title = {{\bfseries#3} \hfill {\bfseries#4}}
```

with the same effects and without lots of open files.

Anyway, to those of you that like to debug codes to discover what is the exact nature of the issue (something ahead of my own abilities), I let a preamble MWE that in my system reproduce the problem.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[tables]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hanging}

\definecolor {secondtablecolor} {HTML} {E6E6DC}
\newtcolorbox{eblock}[4][]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  skin                = bicolor,
  boxrule             = 0pt,
  fontupper           = \sffamily,
  fontlower           = \sffamily,
  fonttitle           = \sffamily,
  colframe            = #2,
  coltitle            = white,
  interior style      = {left color=secondtablecolor,right color=white},
  colbacklower        = white,
  left                = 2pt,
  right               = 2pt,
  top                 = 2pt,
  bottom              = 2pt,
  middle              = 1pt,
  before upper*       = {\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{hangparas}{1em}{1}},
  after upper*        = {\end{hangparas}\end{minipage}},
  segmentation at break = false,
  title               = {
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=0pt,colsep=0pt}
    \begin{tblr}{Xr}
      {\bfseries#3} & {\bfseries#4}\\
    \end{tblr}
  },
  sharpish corners,
  #1
}
\begin{document}
   % Really lots of tcolorboxes like the below to reproduce the issue.
   \begin{eblock}{green}{Test}{Test}
      Test
      \tcblower
      Test
   \end{eblock}
\end{document}
```